# Consider a system of equations $Ax=b$ and $A \tilde x = \tilde b$. Find upper and lower bounds on $\frac{\|x-\tilde x\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_{\infty}}$

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, number-systems, numerical-optimization

> Consider a system of equations $Ax=b$ and $A \tilde x = \tilde b$. Find upper and lower bounds on $\frac{\|x-\tilde x\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_{\infty}}$ compared with $\frac{\|b-\tilde b\|_{\infty}}{\|b\|_{\infty}}$.

So far $\|Ax-A\tilde x\|_{\infty}\leq \|A\|\|x-\tilde x\|_{\infty}$ and $\|b\|_{\infty}\leq \|A\|\|x\|_{\infty}$ but failed to combine them. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392992/matrix-condition-number-and-loss-of-accuracy) and my answer.  The upper bound part is proven there. You might want to skip these lines, if you want to prove it yourself.  Still the rest of that answer might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: @P.Siehr Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use also $x=A^{-1}b$. This should lead to a bound related to the condition number of the matrix $A$.